# n-number of nested inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I have a sql-statement which correctly fetches data from one table. However, I need to fetch in the same way from n number of tables named `table_n`. All of these tables contain a 3-field primary key of `projid`, `docid` and `revnr`. I need to return `n` as `docType` as well, to differentiate the tables. The result will be sorted by `projid` and/or `docid`.

I tried sorting all the outputs from the different queries in PHP but it was way too slow (at least a few seconds on a 3MB database). I'm convinced MySQL/MSSQL will do it faster.

This is my current query:

```
 SELECT a.*  FROM   `table_1` a  
        INNER JOIN (SELECT docid,  
                           Max(revnr) max_val  
                    FROM   `table_1`  
                    WHERE  ( projid = something )  
                    GROUP  BY docid) b  
                ON a.docid = b.docid  
                   AND a.revnr = b.max_val  ORDER  BY docid DESC
```

My current query gets the rows with highest `revnr` for each `docid` and `projid`.

I'm developing on MySQL but I need it to work on MSSQL as well. A general SQL solution would be great.

Thanks!

EDIT: Table schemas of the tables i currently have:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_1` (
  `projid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `docid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `revnr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `revname` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `signedOn` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `sign` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ritningsnr` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `moment` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `omrade` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `stop` datetime NOT NULL,
  `extTodo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`projid`,`docid`,`revnr`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='egenkontroll';



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_2` (
  `projid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `docid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `revnr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `revname` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `signedOn` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `sign` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `extWater` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `extRisk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `extSystem` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `extHelp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `extProvtryck` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `extDoc` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `extEgenkontroll` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'exttabell',
  `extOther` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `extMontorer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`projid`,`docid`,`revnr`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='arbetsberedning';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_3` (
  `projid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `docid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `revnr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `revname` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `adress` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `pipesMark` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `pipesKulvert` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `pipesBasement` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `pipesVaning` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `pipesIngjutna` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ledningTappvatten` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ledningVarmevatten` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ledningHetvatten` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ledningKylaPrim` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ledningKylaSek` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ledningGas` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ledningLuft` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ledningAvlopp` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ledningOther` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `materialGjutjarn` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `materialSteel` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `materialKoppar` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `materialPlast` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `materialRostfritt` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `materialOther` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `omfattningLength` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'meter',
  `omfattningDimension` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `omfattningRitningnr` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `doneWithPump` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `doneWithVattenledning` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `doneWithKompressor` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `doneWithTathetsprovare` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `tryckmedieVatten` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `tryckmedieLuft` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `tryckmedieOther` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `manometerDiameter` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'mm',
  `manometerGradering` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'kPa',
  `manometerReadPressure` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `manometerTid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'sekunder',
  `testedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  `testedBy` varchar(128) NOT NULL COMMENT '"id_" + (userid)',
  `comments` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `commentsBy` varchar(128) NOT NULL COMMENT '"id_" + (userid)',
  `signedOn` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `sign` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`projid`,`docid`,`revnr`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The fields I need are `projid`, `docid`, `revnr`, `revname`, `signedOn`, `sign` and are present in all current and future tables.

Comment: can you show some table schema of the other tables? how are they related with each other? there is a better way to do this in `SQL Server`.

Comment: Do you have a vary number of tables?

Comment: I'm adding tables, yes. I don't need to select data from the older ones that often, but they have to be kept.

Comment: Shouldn't the `ON` have `AND a.projid = something` as well?